# SharePoint Online 2013 o365 Personal Site vs Mysite

Tags: sharepoint-online, my-site, personalization, office-365

Fresh o365 instance.  Noticed the SITES link in SPO gives you a personal page.  Also noticed SPO (somewhere) offers you the option to create a My Site host.

- on o365/spo 2013 What's the difference between a Personal page and My Site?
- Anything we can do to centrally change the layout of a personal page?
- Is it easily possible to change default Personal Page? Change the layout? restrict parts of the page? force promote content or alerts on that page?
- Where is promoted sites stored and updated?
- Can we make the personal site  restricted for modification? how about conditional by user?